# *Batch* Repeat a block of commands in multiple locations?

Tags: batch-file, command, dos

I am writing a mini batch program with a moving "@" in a grid of 3x3.
I am looking to use this block of code in 5 places:

```
if %face%==up set /a x=%x%+1  
if %face%==left set /a y=%y%+1  
if %face%==down set /a x=%x%-1  
if %face%==right set /a y=%y%-1
```

(x and y's are mixed up but don't worry about that)

I could copy paste it a few times but i would like to know if there is a better way of doing it :)

So I want a "variable" containing that code and put the "variable" in the places where I need it instead of copy pasting it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can make a sudo-function like:

```
goto skip_face_func
:face_func
set x=%1
set y=%2
if not defined x set x=0
if not defined y set y=0
if %face%==up set /a x=%x%+1  
if %face%==left set /a y=%y%+1  
if %face%==down set /a x=%x%-1  
if %face%==right set /a y=%y%-1 
goto :eof
:skip_face_func


:: Making x=1 y=4
call :face_func 1 4
echo x:%x% y:%y%

:: Making x=5 y=2
call :face_func 5 2
echo x:%x% y:%y%
```

Comment: Thanks, I ended up making a part called :block and pasted the code in there and just put goto block in the places where I needed it. Did not think it would work but it did. Thanks anyway :P